# ActiveAndroid unresolved symbol Cache

Tags: android, android-sqlite, activeandroid

I'm working on implementing the use of SQLite into my android application. I am using ActiveAndroid. I believe it's installed correctly: I can import `com.activeandroid.Model` successfully, as well as the annotations `import com.activeandroid.annotation.Column`. I have `android:name="com.activeandroid.app.Application"` in the AndroidManifest.xml. I am using Android Studio as my IDE.

But when I try to add the following method to my model, I get an error on `Cache`:

```
public static Cursor fetchResultCursor() {
    String tableName = Cache.getTableName();
    String resultRecords = new Select(tableName + ".*, " + tableName + ".Id as _id").
        from(Item.class).toSql();
    Cursor resultCursor = Cache.openDatabase().rawQuery(resultRecords, null);
    return resultCursor;
}
```

I tried manually adding `import com.activeandroid.Cache;` to the imports, but even then it doesn't recognize it. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
Once I reinstalled ActiveAndroid, the problem went away. I don't understand how before it only installed some ActiveAndroid classes but not others.

Comment: if `import com.activeandroid.Cache;` doesn't work, try to restart your IDE, refresh all libraries and check that you have added the correct library version. That thing exists and must resolve.

Comment: @zapl Restarting doesn't work. I don't know if this helps, but it also won't recognize SQLiteUtils.